# How to get the list of nested ssh connections

Tags: ssh

Is it possible to have a stacktrace like list from ssh:

```
local~$ ssh machine01
machine01~$ ssh machine02
machine02~$ ssh machine03
machine03~$ Desired Command # <------------
   machine02
   machine01
   local
```

Answer (score 2):

Normally not - that could be seen as a security issue.

You can only get the address of the machine originating the current connection (or of the closest firewall behind which the machine resides if it is behind one or more firewalls) (machine02 in your example)  from the SSH_CONNECTION env var:

> ```
>  SSH_CONNECTION        Identifies the client and server ends of the connection.  The variable contains
>                        four space-separated values: client IP address, client port number, server IP
>                        address, and server port number.
> ```

Now if the machines you chain through are all trusted and share some storage between them (your homedir, for example) it's possible to devise a scheme leaving a crumb trail on that shared storage which can be used to extract such trace.